# Download a renderer webpage (from CLI)

Tags: javascript, html, bash

Dynamic webpages makes difficult to extract the *whole* contenent of a webpage.
Especially those  contenent who's generated "on fly" as the page is viewed.
This content can't be saved with curl/wget and even when you're viewing the webpage in the browser ([ctrl]+S usually just save the plain sources and direct dependencies like images and stuff.. but not the dynamic content: tested with Firefox).

There's any way (or browser html5 capable) who's able to store the whole dynamic contenet (sort of "snapshot" html source taken after the whole contenents (dynamic one included) is downloaded?

Something I can use from CLI.
I could manually do this by simply: wait for the page fully rendered > select all > copy > paste

Which would be very time consuming with many given urls

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You question in it's current state is of topic for this site and _may be closed_. Please visit the [help] to make sure that your [question is valid](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and, if so, look at what make a good, [on-topic question that can be answered](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Try PhantomJS: it's a headless browser, which can execute javascript.

```
$ phantomjs save_page.js http://example.com > page.html
```

with `save_page.js`:

```
var system = require('system');
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open(system.args[1], function()
{
    console.log(page.content);
    phantom.exit();
});
```